# Xcode two projects - one for business logic, another for UI?

Tags: ios, xcode, workspace

Is what I am suggesting in the tittle possible?

The main goal is to completely separate the business logic (to be reused in other lightly rebranded apps) and the custom UI for a particular client.

That means, I would have the same core, but on top of it would be very small view controllers driving customised UIs.

I understand that I can have a workspace containing two projects...But should they be peers?
OR should one project consume/include the other one? 
There is no need for app delegate for UI code. It is already in the business logic project. 
How should i organise my projects structure so that the latter is able to use the first with business logic?

Answer (score 1):

You can use different targets: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html

In the same project you can separate the different implementations (assets, xbis...) using the targets. You can also specify different pre-processor flags for each target and use #ifdef

Comment: The core business logic project needs to be maintainable separately completely independently with its own repository and team., with its own CI job...etc.etc..making absolutely sure there are no hidden or unforeseen dependencies.

Comment: So you need to create two different projects in the same workspace.
A library project that handles with all the business login and a iOS project that imports the lib with the business logic and handles the UI.

Answer (score 0):

The better design would be, having the business logic in a static library inside your main project. It is not a good idea to mix UI code in a business logic target. You can add Bundle to your static library to hold resource files such as plists & etc.

I used this approach in one of an enterprise app project. So far so good. We can simply scale, extend & modify the business logic  without affecting the presentation logic.